# What is the expected value of the norm of a random vector with Gaussian distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, normed-spaces

Let's assume I have a zero-mean Gaussian random vector $x$ with co-variance matrix $\Sigma$. Is there a closed form equation for $\mathbb E[||x||]= \mathbb E[\sqrt{x^T x}]$?

Comment: The usual expression is a finite number of terms involving the variances $(\sigma_i)$ and the co-variances $(c_{ij})$.  $\sum_i \sigma_i^2+\sum_i\sum_{j\ne i}c_{ij}$.

Comment: Assume without loss of generality you've diagonalised $\Sigma$, so its eigenvalues are $\Sigma_i:=\Sigma_{ii}$. The pdf of $x$ is $\prod_i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\Sigma_i}}\exp -\frac{x_i^2}{2\Sigma_i}$. You want the mean of $\sqrt{\sum_i x_i^2}$, which sadly is hard in general. When $\Sigma$ is a multiple of the identity matrix, however, it's easy, because the length is $\sqrt{\Sigma_1}$ times a $\chi_n$-distributed variable of mean $\sqrt{2}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}$ if $x$ is $n$-dimensional.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/144893/119261

Answer (score 1):

The usual expression is a finite number of terms involving the variances $(\sigma_i)$ and the co-variances $(c_{ij})$.  $E||x||^2=\sum_i \sigma_i^2+\sum_i\sum_{j\ne i}c_{ij}$.

Comment: This is square of the norm which is very easy. I am interested in the expected value of the norm.

Comment: Could you spell out precisely what you mean by "expected value of the norm"?  Is it the description given by J.G.?

Comment: J.G.' s answer is correct. Looks like there is not closed form solution for the expected value of the norm

Comment: @herbsteinberg could you explain why the covariance is included here? it makes sense if the vector is mean zero-centered that the E[X]^2 = 0, therefore, E[X^2] = the sum of the variances for every element. However, where does the covariance come from here?

Comment: @Learning stats by example Covariance comes from $x_ix_j$ terms  for $i\ne j$ in the definition.

Comment: @herbsteinberg OK I understand. I didn't know the formula for $E[X_1^2 + .. X_i^2]$